# OpenVPN DNS on non rooted device

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, dns, openvpn

I am trying to get OpenVPN working on my Android device using the official OpenVPN app from the app store.  I am running on a Verizon S6 running 5.1.1 and do not have root on the device.  I have generated all the keys and installed the OpenVPN profile on the device.  I successfully connect to the VPN as shown in both the server logs and the fact that I can access local webservers that are only present on the remote LAN such as a printer and the router.  However I am unable to browse to any internet site.  I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 from the device and it was successful. Any attempt to access a URL or even go directly to the google ip resolved by the server results in a DNS error.  What is the right way to configure the DNS so that I can browse the internet through my VPN.  I am able to use the VPN expected on an iPhone and a Macbook so all the necessary NAT rules and such are in place on the server.

Android Config File

```
client

dev tun

proto udp

remote $SERVER$ 1194

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

ca ca.crt
cert androidPhone.crt
key androidPhone.key

comp-lzo

verb 3

setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
setprop net.dns2 4.2.2.1
```

I tried it both with and without the setprop net.dns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my server config was missing the "push DNS ...." option.  My other devices worked because I had set a DNS server in the adapter settings that overrode the lack of a DNS server being pushed by the OpenVPN server.